# Send udp packet on LAN from web browser

Tags: php, networking, browser, udp

I have built a simple TAPI app that will run on a machine on the LAN that connects to the office PBX, it allows me to receive dial, answer, hangup etc commands (which I was planning on receiving via a udp packet). I did this with the intention to integrate the office CRM system to the phone system.

Having done this and testing using a simple python app to send the udp packets I find myself wondering how to send the udp packets to this app given that the CRM system is a web app written in php/javascript.

We use Firefox in the office and so I was going to start with a Firefox extension, but I thought I would ask and see if anyone has any experience on sending udp packets over a lan from a browser using java or flash or from a browser extension/plugin.

Or is there a better cross browser way to send commands to an app on a network pc when the web app is hosted online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe in the CRM you could use javascript and JSONP to make a request to a local HTTP server, and that server could then send the UDP packets instead.